# how to install postgis on postgres15 on an amazon linux 2

Tags: node.js, postgis, geos, postgresql-15, postgis-installation

I have Postgres-15 installed with geos-3.9.1 and postgis-3.2.1 on my Amazon Linux 2 machine. I have a problem with the installing postgis. I've built and installed everything from source.

The error I'm getting when I run CREATE EXTENSION postgis; is:ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/lib64/pgsql/postgis-3.so": libgeos_c.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

- I installed geos and postgis from source
- I configured pgadmin with the ec2 instance
- I'm struggling with postgis it give the previous error !!
- help me developers